# How to manage access in a projects of solution

Tags: tfs

I have a solution that contains several projects, I want a team to work on this source code, but every developer can only see his own project and can't see the rest of the projects. But he can build and run the whole solution. What solution do you have for this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to achieve this no matter you are using **TFVC** or **Git** as your source control.

TFS build is using **build service account** not the user which trigger build. Once the build service account have appropriate permission, it will get source from  TFS server and download to build agent.

The permission in TFS is mutual independence. And permissions can be granted directly to an individual user, or to a group.

In version control permissions, explicit **deny** takes precedence over administrator group permissions.

You could deny the **Read** permission for those users. And set the other related [**build permission**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#object-permissions) such as *view build definition* and *queue build* to **allow**.

> **Read**
>
> Can read the contents of a file or folder. If a user has Read
>   permissions for a folder, the user can see the contents of the folder
>   and the properties of the files in it, even if the user does not have
>   permission to open the files.

---

> **Queue builds**  Can queue new builds.
>
> **View build definition** Can view build definition(s).
>
> **View builds**   Can view builds belonging to build definition(s).
>
> ...

However, there is still some difference for Git and TFVC for control project permission：

In TFVC you can open the web portal  and go to the code tab. There you can right click on any folder and select permissions. You can use any fine grain you like and control inheritance.

In Git you can  only control permission ls at the Repository  and Branch level.

Besides, you may also need a account with full permission of solution and all projects to  create the build pipeline. Otherwise, the user may not able to select the mapping relationship in source get configuration.